# max-in-flight kafka vs reactor

Tags: spring-kafka, reactor-kafka

Kafka has `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection` property. `reactor-kafka` has maxInflight here - https://projectreactor.io/docs/kafka/release/reference/#api-guide-sender.

Updating this value does not change `max.in.flight.requests.per.connection`.

How are they different? can you give specific examples on their usage?

Answer (score 0):

The `SenderOptions` value is used in the `.publishOn` operator...

```
.publishOn(senderOptions.scheduler(), senderOptions.maxInFlight());
```

The Kafka option https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#producerconfigs_max.in.flight.requests.per.connection

> The maximum number of unacknowledged requests the client will send on a single connection before blocking.

In the reactive world, blocking is a no no.

Comment: I do understand that blocking is a no in the reactive world. But reactor-kafka is a wrapper around KafkaProducer. KafkaProducer internally uses max.in.flight.requests.per.connection. so how can reactor-kafka get around the blocking behavior?

Comment: The publishOn operator accepts prefetch. if thats what maxInFlight means,  it will just affect the producer which produces sender records.

Comment: `>get around the blocking behavior?` by setting the prefetch to a smaller number.